# Can't get value in ngoninit on subscribe angular

Tags: angular, subscribe, ngoninit

I don't understand why my object is always "undefinned" on ngoninit on angular. 
I request on my api project i get my response correctly. 
When I `console.log` my object is not defined (ngoninit) but in other function i can get values.

My questions is why and how can i do to get my object in ngoninit.

Thank you

I retrieve my response correctly on postman
others functions retrieve too

Service:

```
getById(id:string):Observable<Grower>{
   return this.http.get<Grower>(`${environment.apiUrl}/growers/${id}`);
}
```

View model:

```
export class GrowerDetails {

    adress:string;
    zip:string;
    city:string;
}
```

Component:

```
  growerService:GrowerService;

  detailsProfil: GrowerDetails;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, growerService:GrowerService,
    private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { 
      this.growerService = growerService;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detailsProfil = new GrowerDetails();

    this.growerService.getById(this.decoded.nameid).subscribe(
      (data:Grower) => this.detailsProfil = {
            adress: data.adress,
            city: data.city,
            zip : data.zip

      },
      error => console.log(error) 
    );
console.log(this.detailsProfil); // undefinned

onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.detailsProfil); // ok
 }
```

Postman:

```
{
    "lat": 0,
    "long": 0,
    "description": "test",
    "adress": "test",
    "zip": "test",
    "city": "test"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: because your subscribe is async, you can console inside of subscribe, you will see the data

Comment: how can i do so ?

Comment: `(data:Grower) => { this.detailsProfil = {...}; console.log(...); }`

Comment: that's mean i can't work with my object outside the subscribe in ngoninit ?

Comment: Outside, yes, but after the observable callback has been executed. If you keep the two `console.log` statements, you will see that your original statement is called before the subscribe callback. See the duplicate question/answer for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can have the value of *detailsProfil* inside the subscription but not outside of it. Because *getById()* is an ***async*** call so, won't wait for subscribe to finish before it executes.

Do some changes like below,

```
 constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, growerService:GrowerService,
    private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { 
      //  this.growerService = growerService;  <- this line not required
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detailsProfil = new GrowerDetails();

    this.growerService.getById(this.decoded.nameid).subscribe((data) => {
       console.log(data);            
       this.detailsProfil.adress = data.adress;
       this.details.city = data.city;
       this.details.zip = data.zip;
     },
      error => console.log(error));
     console.log(this.detailsProfil); // you will get detailsProfil Object
  }
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: ok it works. i don't know why in the doc they say like this : .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = {
    heroesUrl: data['heroesUrl'],
    textfile:  data['textfile']
});

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined because you don't have the data yet.

```
     ngOnInit() {
        this.detailsProfil = new GrowerDetails();

        this.growerService.getById(this.decoded.nameid).subscribe(
          (data:Grower) => {
             this.detailsProfil = {adress: data.adress,city: data.city,zip : data.zip };

             console.log(this.detailsProfil); // you can access here because you got it now.
          },
          error => console.log(error) 
        );

    console.log(this.detailsProfil); // you can't access here. it's still undefined 
  }
```